# dynamics crm 2011: change look of form and/or record in a view based on a value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to change the look of a form as well as a record in list view based on a simple value.

For example, for all records that have an email address:

1. make the form yellow
2. make the record in a view red.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply css as WebResources. You can see some examples here:

- http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/08/crm-2011-form-customization-part-2.html
- http://weblogs.asp.net/gayanperera/archive/2010/06/30/how-to-change-the-grid-icons-dynamically.aspx

In Codeplex there is a [tool](http://crm2011templates.codeplex.com/) some templates. Take a look.

Comment: Just highlighting as per my own answer, +1 to Pedro but these are UNSUPPORTED changes.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do either of those things in a supported manner. **The correct approach here is to challenge the requirement.** Unsupported changes risk your solution being broken without notice in the future. This is especially true of CRM Online (I know that you haven't said that you are using that though).

+1 to Pedro anyway, since despite being unsupported, his suggestions will achieve your aim.